# python fabric run awk command return a KeyError: 'print $1'

Tags: python, docker, fabric

I am using python fabric run command, it doesn't work and give me a KeyError:

```
run('docker ps -a | grep {} | awk "{print $1}"'.format(container_name))
KeyError: 'print $1'
```

But if I replace .format with %s, it works, how could that be possible:

```
run("docker ps -a | grep %s | awk '{print $1}'" % container_name)
```

My python version 2.7.8, ".format()" definitely could work, it seems to be related with "awk" command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Format is trying to substitute for `{print $1}` and of course there is no such key.

You can escape the {} by surrounding them with {} so:

```
run('docker ps -a | grep {} | awk "{{print $1}}"'.format(container_name))
```

Should work - as a test:
iPython 3.0:

```
In [1]: container_name = 'fred'

In [2]: 'docker ps -a | grep {} | awk "{{print $1}}"'.format(container_name)
Out[2]: 'docker ps -a | grep fred | awk "{print $1}"'
```

Python:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> container_name = 'fred'
>>> 'docker ps -a | grep {} | awk "{{print $1}}"'.format(container_name)
'docker ps -a | grep fred | awk "{print $1}"'
>>>
```

Comment: I have added a couple of tests that I ran.

Comment: I think I have some typo just now. Thanks.